# Taxonomy counter on Taxonomy List(plugin)

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, taxonomy

I'm using this plugin (Taxonomy List by Muhammad Rehman) and apparently is not longer on develop or support.
 
I need to show the main taxonomy (custom from my theme) and the child's taxonomies with the count of elements inside. But after a long trying can't resolve the problem and this is my result:

Florida (0) <<<< Must be 3 not 1, because his children's has 1 each one.
- Jacksonville (1)
 
- Miami (1) 
- Saint Petersburg (1) 

This must dynamically for each taxonomy.

Comment: Sounds like it may be easier to loop through the terms yourself and include the child count in the parent total. Do you have any code to share for your template as we may be able to help with an example.

Comment: The plugin Im using is this one:https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-list/
and the taxonomy is: cf47rs_property_location

Comment: No one?  any help?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, what code have you modified to display the count? Are you using the shortcode `[taxonomy_list name="cf47rs_property_location"]` If the plugin doesn't display the total of the child items, then it's going to be best to write your own shortcode to display the terms with the correct count. Are you adding this code to a widget?